# javascript - How to prevent document.write going outside the Div box?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a fight log where combat information will go inside a div box that holds about 15 lines. After 16+ lines, the text goes through the box and starts heading south.

Is there a way in Javascript to say "hey, after 15 lines, create a new line, and delete the last line!".

I'm thinking I would set this up with arrays. Would that be correct? Where I would say something along the lines of.. 15 elements, and after 16 elements, delete last element and push a new element?

This is all I have for code:

```
document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += "Fight Log";
```

After 15+ of these, it goes outside the DIV Fight Log box.

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Post your code and we can edit it to suit your requirements.

Comment: You should wrap "Fight Log" in an element such as a paragraph and use document.getElementsByClassName("p"), check the length and if it matches your requirements remove the first/last (whatever you wish).

Comment: overflow scroll? nicer imo to add a clean scrollbar and scroll to the bottom every time new content is added.

Comment: document.createElement would be better for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Here is the JSFiddle for it**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hd2CC/)

Wrap your log message with `span` so that it turns into a selectable DOM item. Select the last one when it is 15+ and delete it. Here how it is done.

```
function addMessage(message) {
    var logElement = document.getElementById('log');
    var elements = document.getElementById('log').getElementsByTagName('span');
    var length = elements.length;
    if(length >= 15) {
        logElement.removeChild(elements[length-1]);
    }
    logElement.innerHTML += "<span>" + message + "</span>";
}

for(var i=1; i<30; i++) {
    addMessage('Figth Log ' + i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding those messages to an array, and re-rendering all the messages every time. This way you can use array methods to manage the number of messages:

```
var log = [],
  messageElem = document.getElementById("log");    

function addMessage(message) {
  log.push(message);
  while (log.length > 16) {
    log.shift();
  }
  messageElem.innerHTML = log.join("\n");
}


... then later ...

addMessage('Fight Log');
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your div is, It might have the fixed size. Try specifying style="overflow:auto;" so it shows the scroll-bars once messages go out of bounds.